# Behaviour change when enctype attribute missing on <form> tag

Tags: php, apache, forms, enctype

I recently switched from a VPS server to a dedicated server. For some reason, on a custom CMS I was working on, all the forms stopped working. Instead of processing the block of execution under `if($_POST)` it would just re-load an empty form. So I experimented by adding  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. That worked...

Anyhow, I'm wondering, before I commit to changing ALL my forms, is there a PHP setting of some sort that I'm missing that would fix this universally?

Comment: It could possibly be because of your change in environment -- charset, doctype, etc.

Answer (score 1):

there could be some reasons:

if you don't set **enctype="multipart/form-data"** although you send some files in your form

or if there is a wrong value in the php.ini in **post_max_size**, 
for example if in php.ini is written post_max_size=**8MB** instead of **8M** then php will treat this as 0 cause 8MB is not a valid value.
if so, then no data can be transmitted by post